# Getting data from amazon.com + python

Tags: python, mysql

Basically I need to get data from amazon.com such as product and their prices just for viewing database design and then insert them in sql tables .

But how should i proceed in getting and parsing the data...

Can anybody lead me to the correct direction and even tell me the legalities involved in the issue.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Legal expertise isn't Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

For parsing the HTML, you will want to use something like Beautiful Soup:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

For downloading the HTML, use urllib or urllib2, which is included in the Python standard library.

For legalese, talk to a lawyer. But the standard library does include a robotsparser library for parsing robots.txt, which is generally something you're supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are several Python libraries for querying Amazon product data:

- [python-amazon-product-api](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-product-api/)
- [bottlenose](https://github.com/dlo/bottlenose)
- [PyAWS](http://trac2.assembla.com/pyaws)

For legalese read [Amazon.com Product Advertising API License Agreement](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html) and talk to a lawyer.